# thrust exception bulk_kernel_by_value in transform_reduce

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

I'm working on a optimization problem which contains various math functions which resembles in similar form, so I warp them in a `FunctionObj`

```
template <typename T>
struct FunctionObj
{
    T a;
     FunctionObj(): a(1)
    {
    }
};
```

And defines a `FuncEval` to evaluate

```
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__  inline T FuncEval(const FunctionObj<T> &f_obj, T x)
{
    return f_obj.a+x;
}
```

What I really want to do is `sum {func(x)}`, so I defines a `FuncEvalF` functor to make use of `thrust::tranform_reduce`

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncEvalF
{
    const FunctionObj<T>& f_obj;
    __host__ __device__ inline FuncEvalF(const FunctionObj<T>& in_f_obj) :f_obj(in_f_obj)
{

}
    __host__ __device__ inline T operator()(T x)
    {
        return FuncEval(f_obj, x);
    }
};

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ inline T BatchFuncEval(const FunctionObj<T>  &f_obj, int size, const T *x_in);
template<>
inline float BatchFuncEval< float>(const FunctionObj<float>  &f_obj, int size, const float *x_in)
{
    return thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::device, thrust::device_pointer_cast(x_in), thrust::device_pointer_cast(x_in + size), FuncEvalF<float>(f_obj), static_cast<float>(0), thrust::plus<float>());
}
```

Finally in the `main.cu` I call the `transform_reduce`

```
auto func = FuncEvalF<float>(FunctionObj<float>());
    float result = 0;
    try
    {
        result = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::device, thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_a), thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_a + 10000), func, static_cast<float>(0), thrust::plus<float>());

    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        printf("%s in thurst \n ", e.what());
    }
```

Here the exception comes : `bulk_kernel_by_value`, even I change the 10000 to 10. Thing only goes better when I change the defintion of `FuncEval` to

```
return x;
```

The program would output the right but meaningless answer . I can't help asking what's wrong with my code ? Thank you for your attention.
The complete code below, cuda 7.0 sm_20

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
struct FunctionObj
{
    T a;
     FunctionObj(): a(1)
    {
    }

};

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__  inline T FuncEval(const FunctionObj<T> &f_obj, T x)
{
    return f_obj.a+x;
}


template <typename T>
struct FuncEvalF
{
    const FunctionObj<T>& f_obj;
    __host__ __device__ inline FuncEvalF(const FunctionObj<T>& in_f_obj) :f_obj(in_f_obj)
    {

    }
    __host__ __device__ inline T operator()(T x)
    {
        return FuncEval(f_obj, x);
    }
};
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ inline T BatchFuncEval(const FunctionObj<T>  &f_obj, int size, const T *x_in);
template<>
inline float BatchFuncEval< float>(const FunctionObj<float>  &f_obj, int size, const float *x_in)
{
    return thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::device, thrust::device_pointer_cast(x_in), thrust::device_pointer_cast(x_in + size), FuncEvalF<float>(f_obj), static_cast<float>(0), thrust::plus<float>());
}
int main()
{
    cudaError_t cudaE;
    float a[10000] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    float* dev_a;
    cudaE = cudaMalloc((void**)(&dev_a), sizeof(float) * 10000);
    cudaE = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeof(float) * 10000, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    auto func = FuncEvalF<float>(FunctionObj<float>());
    float result = 0;
    try
    {
        result = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::device, thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_a), thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_a + 10000), func, static_cast<float>(0), thrust::plus<float>());

    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        printf("%s in thurst \n ", e.what());
    }
    printf("the gpu float result is %f\n", result);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
}
```

Comment: Please convert the code you have posted into a short, complete working example which illustrates your problem. Without that it is not possible to say what the problem is

Comment: Ok, I just paste all the codes here.

Comment: Could you post a version without the bad language in the code? If you want to be treated like an adult, treat everyone else here like one too.

Comment: Sorry, updated. Fighting it whole day makes me mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `f_obj` within `struct FuncEvalF` is a `const FunctionObj<T>&`.

It is instantiated as a temporary on the host `FunctionObj<float>()`, but the reference to it is not valid anymore later on.

One way to fix this is to create a copy of it instead of holding a reference to it:

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncEvalF
{
    FunctionObj<T> f_obj;
    ....
}
```

Comment: That fixes the problem. Thank you very much. I'm trying to move all the `Func` related Object to the device memory with `thrust::device_vector<Func>[1]`  before I refreshed this page.  Finally relieved , yeah.